# how to install modules through pycharm

Tags: python, module

I am a PyCharm user and I was always wondering how to install a module.

I tried using command prompt but it could not define python

Answer (score 3):

On the bottom bar there is a tab called "Python Packages". You can search for packages you want to install there. When you select a package there will be a install button on the right.

[image: Tab "Python Packages"]

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm press ctrl+alt+s, then go to the Python Interpreter and press the plus button to look for the module you want. From there you can search for example pandas or numpy, and install it.

Follow this [link](https://www.edureka.co/community/48134/how-to-install-modules-in-pycharm)